# Flutter check if DateTime actually exists

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datetime-format

In my app the user can add a `DateTime`. For that I am not using a simple `DatePicker` but instead something custom, where I get two `Strings` for each Day & Month (dd, mm). My problem right now is that I need to validate this input. And I tried a couple of things but couldn't get a good working solution!

```
  DateTime getDateTime(BuildContext context) {
    return DateTime(2021, (m1! * 10 + m2!), (d1! * 10 + d2!));
  }
```

This is what Ive tried. The problem is that the user can also give me anything (any `int`) for m1, m2, d1 and d2 and `DateTime` simply formats that in a regular DateTime.

Is there a way to check if a given DateTime in the past existed?

**German format**

> 01.05. -> true

> 00.05. -> false

> 51.05. -> false

> 31.02. -> false

> 15.10. > true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented by using 'parseStrict' method in DateFormat.

The 'parseStrict' throw exception does not match real date.

```
bool isValidDate({y = 2021, m1, m2, d1, d2}) {
    DateFormat format = DateFormat('yyyy/M/d');
    try {
      String md = '$y/${m1 * 10 + m2}/${d1 * 10 + d2}';
      format.parseStrict(md);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
isValidDate(m1: 1, m2: 1, d1: 3, d2: 0);
```

Comment: `praseStrict` is exactly what I need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We can check that in other way...

```html
static bool isDate(String dt) {
    try {
      final date = DateTime.parse(dt);
      final y = date.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0');
      final m = date.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
      final d = date.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
      final newDt = "$y-$m-$d";
      return dt == newDt;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  if(isDate('2021-02-04){
    //Yes Correct
  } else {
    //Not Correct
  }
```

credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1246063/mikhail-ponkin